# Pushing thousands of holes in extruded shape incredibly slow in Three.js

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js

Using `Three.js` I want to visualise 3 shapes with thousands of differently sized holes (32x133) in each. The holes would take their radius from an array in the final version but for now I just used random sizes. Finally, the shapes would be extruded using `ExtrudeGeometry`.

[image: Shapes with holes]

I have modified an online [example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html) and created a loop to push holes in my shape:

```
var panelW = 450,
    panelH = 1750;

var screenPanel1 = new THREE.Shape();

( function roundedRect( ctx, x, y, width, height, radius ){

    ctx.moveTo( x, y + radius );
    ctx.lineTo( x, y + height - radius );
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo( x, y + height, x + radius, y + height );
    ctx.lineTo( x + width - radius, y + height) ;
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo( x + width, y + height, x + width, y + height - radius );
    ctx.lineTo( x + width, y + radius );
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo( x + width, y, x + width - radius, y );
    ctx.lineTo( x + radius, y );
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo( x, y, x, y + radius );

} )( screenPanel1, 0, 0, panelW, panelH, 10 );

var hsMargin = 30,
    hsDist = 12,
    hsXcount = Math.floor( ( panelW - ( hsMargin * 2 ) ) / hsDist ) + 1,
    hsYcount = Math.floor( ( panelH - ( hsMargin * 2 ) ) / hsDist ) + 1;

var hc = 1;

for (var hx = 0; hx < hsXcount; hx++) {
    // for (var hy = 0; hy < hsYcount; hy++) { //this takes AGES!
    for (var hy = 0; hy < 10; hy++) {

        hsRad = Math.random() * 4 + 1;
        var hsX = hsDist * hx + hsMargin + hsRad;
        var hsY = hsDist * hy + hsMargin + hsRad;

        var holePath = new THREE.Path();
        holePath.moveTo( hsX, hsY );
        holePath.absarc( hsX-hsRad, hsY, hsRad, 0, Math.PI*2, true );
        screenPanel1.holes.push( holePath );

        hc++;
        info.innerHTML = 'holes: ' + hc;

    }

}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fallenartist/0e8jmyqv/)

This is incredibly slow even for just 10 rows of holes.

Am I doing it wrong? Or is there a better approach?

EDIT: Have just found this [issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4920) on GitHub and it seems it's the current triangulation method that's responsible for the slow performance in my case (using lots of holes). This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fallenartist/0e8jmyqv/1/) uses jahting's revision of the Three.js library with Polygon Near-Linear Triangulation and is much much faster. I hope it will end up in the official library!

Comment: Can't say I'm surprised. Draw a row of holes in a bitmap and then copy and paste it in n times would be one way to speed it up.

Comment: Can't copy/paste. Each hole is unique in size...